# Internet explorer -11 -Developer tools(F12) ->Emulation tab ->Document mode is not displaying IE 11 option

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, registry, internet-explorer-11

Internet explorer -11 -Developer tools(F12) ->Emulation tab ->Document mode is not displaying IE 11 option instead its displaying Edge,10,9,8 .

IE - Version: 11.0.9600.19541
IE - Update Version: 11.0.160(KB4525106)
Windows server 2012 64 bit

Why 11 is missing here? Is there any way I can make 11 to be appear here by updating registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a naming issue. Prior to Windows 10 when the Edge browser started, the compatibility modes listed the latest version (version of that browser) as "Edge" in IE. You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255001(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#mode). They renamed that setting when Win10 came out.

> **Edge (Default)** represents all the latest standards and features IE11 supports.

In your case, you're using IE 11, so the "Edge" option is IE 11 actually. I think you can only install the latest update to get the "IE 11" option instead of editing the registry. In my Windows Server 2016, IE version 11.3564.14393.0, update version 11.0.180(KB4540671), it has the "IE 11" option, so you can try to update the version.